# Nested Routes with react router 5

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to switch in nested child elements.Here is my code:

`index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`App.js`:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/component" component={ Component }/>
    <Route exact path="/component/test" component={ Test }/>
    <Route exact path="/component/test/ui" component={ Ui }/>
</Switch>
```

`Ui.js`:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
    <Navbar>
        <Link to='/component/test/ui/page'>
            Page
    </Link>
        <Link to='/component/test/ui/element' >
            Element
    </Link>
    </Navbar>
    <Switch>
        <Route
            exact path='/component/test/ui/page'
            component={Page}
        />
        <Route
            exact path='/component/test/ui/element'
            component={Element}
        />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Now in `Ui` component I want switch this child elements.
This code is working when I clicked on Page or Element links, but  It's not working when page refreshing or searching on addressbar.
**Note:** I don't want to import `Ui` component in `App.js`. Also you can suggest me using Redux.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "but It's not working when page refreshing or searching on addressbar."? What's happening? Also, you shouldn't have a second `Router` element inside `Ui.js`.

Comment: 1. In Ui.js component when clicked on Page link, it's rendering properly and opening '/component/test/ui/page'. But when I refresh in Page component it's not rendering.. not opening '/component/test/ui/page'.

Comment: 2. If I don't use second Route in Ui.js then not working. Please help I'm stuck here.. What is the correct solutions.